# Log out in multiple auth in Laravel 5

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.3, laravel-routing, laravel-authorization

I am using Laravel's default authentication for multiple authentication. I have two types of user admin and normal user. For admins I have used admin guard,It works fine if i'm logged in as 2 types of user in different browser but the problem is when I am logged in both as admin and user in the same browser at the time of logging out it is redirecting me to the admin login page.I want to be redirect if I logged out from admin panel then to the admin login page else if i log out from user panel it should redirect me to the '/' route. Here is my code of logout method in authenticates user file.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->check()) $redirect = '/admin/login';
        else $redirect = '/';

        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect($redirect);
    }
```

here is the logout form in both side admin and user.

```
<a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a>
```

now how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm from what I understand when you logout as an admin & user you still want to be sent back to the `/` route. I'd suggest just removing your check for if the current user is an admin and by default sending the user back home.

Comment: actually not that. If i log out from admin it should redirect me to the admin login page else if i log out from user panel it should redirect me to the '/' route.

Comment: What do you get when you `dd(Auth::guard('admin')->check())` if you put it above your if statement.